# Compare DateTime getting hours

Tags: c#, datetime, hour

I created a counter hours using two DataTimePickers (t1 and t2) where

```
    if(t1<t2)
       hour = t2-t1
    else
       hour = t2 - (-t1)
```

just got the results:

```
t1            t2            hour
11:00         23:00         12
11:00         00:00         11
11:00         13:00         2
11:00         03:00         14
```

and what i need is:

```
t1            t2            hour
11:00         23:00         12
11:00         00:00          0
11:00         13:00         2
11:00         03:00         16
```

How do I get this result?

Comment: why should the distance between 11:00 and 0:00 be 0?

Comment: because 0 -- 11 equals 0 + 11 so that will always give +11, 
3 - - 11 does = 14 why the hell would it = 16?

Comment: The differences you got are right, the one's you want arent?

Comment: serious math failure here, the computer should teach you a thing or two!

Comment: I don't understand your output. Explain why `11:00 - 00:00 = 0`, yet `11:00 - 03:00 = 16`. Is `00:00` a special case?

Comment: @RedFilter: for the second, it's perhaps `03:00 of the following day - 11:00 of the current day = (24 + 3) - 11 = 16`. For the first, I'm curious, too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want the difference in the values of the two times or do you want the time difference?  (i.e. should 08:00, 06:00 return 2 or -2)

Also, I'm confused as to why (11:00, 00:00) should return 0.

If you just want the difference in the values, use

```
if (t1<t2)
    hour = t2-t1
else
    hour = t1-t2
```

If you want the time difference, only use

```
hour = t2-t1
```

Comment: i don't know how to explain better, but if i do this(hour = t2-t1), it'll seems like (8 September 09:00) - (9 September 9:00) = 0 and what i need is (8 September 09:00) - (9 September 9:00) = 24

Comment: That explains it much better.  What language are you writing in?

Comment: i'm using c# - windows Forms. i tryed use DateTime.Compare(), but it just return nº of days.

Comment: So you must be assigning the "hour" of the DateTimePickers into t1 and t2?

Comment: not. a user changes value as he want. but the diference never is bigger then 24 hours. As Vlad says (24 + 3) - 11 = 16. So i put it on t1 and t2 ValueChanged: if (t2<t1) (t2+24) - t1.Thanks everybody